# python : multiprocessing managament

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

with multiprocessing python library I can launch multiprocess, like

```
import multiprocessing as mu

def worker(n)
        print "worker:", n
        n = int(1e4)
        for i in range(n):
                for j in range(n):
                        i*j 
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
        jobs = []
        for i in range(5):
                p = mu.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
                jobs.append(p)
                p.start()
```

and I can get the numbers of processors (cpu cores) with

```
np = mu.cpu_count()
```

but if I have a list of process, how I can launch without overcharge the processor ?
if I have a quad core, how I can launch first 4 process? and when finish a process launch other.

#### References

- http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this solution

```
import multiprocessing as mu

def worker(n):
        print "worker:", n
        n = int(1e4/2)
        for i in range(n):
                for j in range(n):
                        i*j
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
        jobs = []
        for i in range(5):
                p = mu.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
                jobs.append(p)

        running = []
        np = mu.cpu_count()

        for i in range(np):
                p = jobs.pop()
                running.append(p)
                p.start()

        while jobs != []:
                for r in running:
                        if r.exitcode == 0:
                                running.remove(r)
                                p = jobs.pop()
                                p.start()
                                running.append(p)
```

Comment: I think you are going to kill the the last `np` processes before they are done.  The main process will finish after you empty `jobs` and will not wait for the sub-processes to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest side stepping the problem and using `multiprocessing.Pool` ([example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), [api](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)).

(modified from the example in the docs)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = Pool(processes=num_proc)
    res = pool.map(f, range(10))
```

Alternately, you can set up a producer/consumer scheme and have a fixed number of long running sub-processes.

A third really quick and dirty way is using one `mu.Queue`.  Note that `get` blocks until it gets a result back.

```
import multiprocessing as mu
import time
res = mu.Queue()

def worker(n):
    print "worker:", n
    time.sleep(1)
    res.put(n)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    np = mu.cpu_count()
    print np
    # start first round
    for j in range(np):
        p = mu.Process(target=worker, args=(j,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    # every time one finishes, start the next one
    for i in range(np,15):
        r = res.get()
        print 'res', r
        p = mu.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    # get the remaining processes 
    for j in range(np):
        r = res.get()
        print 'res', r
```

Comment: I know the `pool.map` but my question is more with, how management sets of process? maybe with `.is_alive()`

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) say this about the `processes` keyword: "If `processes` is `None` then the number returned by `cpu_count()` is used" so what you're suggesting with `num_proc` is what happens by default.

Comment: @martineau fair enough, but it never hurts to make things explicit (I have been bitten by different default behavior between systems/versions (mostly of `matplotlib` styling))